# WYSIHTML5 editor incorrecty parses text entered as HTML code

Tags: javascript, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

If I try to paste HTML code in the rich text editor mode it is parsed incorrectly

E.g.:

- go here http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/
- and try to paste this text: <a href="http://google.com">

The pasted text is parsed and looks ugly, but I want to see it exacly as entered

Comment: You don't need to paste html when it is in show HTML mode, click ***</>*** button which will take you to the source mode and paste your html there

Comment: I know this, but user don't. It's a use case for the app we develop.

Comment: Adn actually I show only text formatting buttons (b,i,u). And user is unable to edit the code.

Comment: Take a look at ***[This](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Configuration)***. Here is the parser, modify it to your needs.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to work only when you paste code in the source mode